# Error : Web Applications using Claims authentication require an update from health analyzer

Tags: health-analyzer

After installing a sharepoint instance(Sp Server standard 2010 Sp1 and Windows 2008 r2 server)  i get some errors being detected by the health analyzer ;
Web Applications using Claims authentication require an update

Category security:
Explanation Web Applications using Claims authentication are at risk for a potential security vulnerability, which may allow users elevation of privileges. 
Remedy A security update is required on each server in the farm. For more information about this rule, see "http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=184705".

it does take be to this update.
But i don't know which update to use as i'm on a Windows 2008 r2 server?
Any ideas how to fix these errors?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi these 2 external article may help you to resolve the issue

1. [Web Applications using Claims authentication require an update - TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff686815%28v=office.14%29.aspx)
2. [Steps](http://sharepointandothercoolstuff.blogspot.in/2011/06/web-applications-using-claims.html)